# App crashes with error message empty array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Have initwithPDFAtPath in AViewController

```
-(id)initWithPDFAtPath:(NSString *)path {

NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
thePDF = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(thePDF);

self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
return self;

 }
```

Trying to open pdf file in BViewController using viewDidLoad method

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//modelArray holds the page numbers

modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int index = 1; index <= totalPages; index++) {

[modelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];

}
thePageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

thePageViewController.delegate = self;
thePageViewController.dataSource = self;

thePageViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl);
AViewController = [[AViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
aViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:aViewController];
```

}

When i execute it crashes with empty array message. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

EDIT:

AViewController has a PDFScrollview

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Create our PDFScrollView and add it to the view controller.
CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(thePDF, [_page intValue]);

pdfScrollView = [[PDFScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 925)];
[pdfScrollView setPDFPage:PDFPage];

[self.view addSubview:pdfScrollView];
  }
```

Comment: Where, exactly, does it crash?

Comment: Perhaps modelArray is empty?

Comment: Verify that `totalPages` is 1 or more.

Comment: totalpages shows correct number which is 20 actuallypdfscrollview in aviewcontroller _page = (NSString*) 0x000000. Modelarray shows 0 objects. found in exception breakpoint.Updated my post please check

Comment: Why did you comment out `[super viewDidLoad]` in your second snippet?

Comment: i removed comment out now but still same result

Comment: I'm guessing you get the error because the array is empty.  That would most likely be because totalPages is zero.  Have you traced execution or inserted NSLog statements to see what's going on???

Comment: What attempts (other than just random modifications) have you made to debug this?  Single stepping?  Logging?

Comment: i checked with single step debugging it shows pdfscrollview = (pdfscrollview*) 0x000000 _page = (nsstring*) 0x000000

Comment: But you didn't step through the setup of modelArray, and you didn't step through the failing reference.  You've done nothing to disprove, eg, the theory that there are two different instances of modelArray you're dealing with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that `totalPages` could not be initialised in `BViewController`.

Also Not sure how you store it, as in `AViewController` you do initialisation of this variable before calling `super init` which could lead to loosing this value.

To fix this I think you need do couple of things.

First in `AViewContoller` change init method to something like this:

```
-(id)initWithPDFAtPath:(NSString *)path {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        _thePDF = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
        _totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(thePDF);
    }

    return self;
 }
```

and store totalPages in parameters.

Than in `BViewController` you need to do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

//modelArray holds the page numbers

thePageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

thePageViewController.delegate = self;
thePageViewController.dataSource = self;

thePageViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl);
AViewController = [[AViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];

modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (aViewController.totalPages > 0) {
   for (int index = 1; index <= aViewController.totalPages; index++) {

     [modelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];

       }

       aViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
   }

        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:aViewController];
    }
```

But really that seems some obvious problems with all Controllers Architecture.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see here, it looks like you initialize `modelArray` before you have a number for `totalPages`, since this is only set in `initWithPDFAtPath`. Although I think you can (and should) reorganize the code so that only one of the view controllers has to manage the page numbers, you can probably fix the issue by moving the line

```
AViewController *aViewController = [[AViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
```

to before the point where you initialize `modelArray`.

Hope this helps!